# Get html from custom route api

Tags: html, rest-api, json

I created a custom route with the wordpress API which allows me to retrieve the html content of the post
When editing a post, I added an "Export to html" link with the download attribute

`echo "<a href='".get_bloginfo('url')."/wp-json/export/post/".$post->ID."' class='button-primary' download>Exporter l'article</a>";`

But when I click on the link I get a .json file

How to transform this .json into .html before downloading the file?
My client will use this html export to import it into another site (not a wordpress site)

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use the `rest_pre_serve_request` hook - see my [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/377954) for an example.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me, it works !